# PHP simplexml_load_string() trouble with double quotes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to load some xml file with simplexml_load_string but im having problems doing so if in the attributes i use double quotes... the thing is that i (think) i did this before with double quotes and worked fine, so i don't know/understand why is failing. this is the xml im trying to load:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <products>
        <product title=”Rimmel Lasting Finish Lipstick 4g” price=”4.99”>
            <category>Lipstick</category>
        </product>
        <product title=”Sebamed Anti-Dandruff Shampoo 200ml” price=”4.99”>
            <category>Shampoo</category>
        </product>
    </products>
    <total>9.98</total>
</order>
```

the error i get is:
`PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 4: parser error : AttValue: &quot; or ' expected in Orders.php on line 42`

then the error continues (I'll post it if there's any need). 
The PHP is:

```
$getXmlString = file_get_contents("../xmls/order_x.xml");
$orderLoaded = simplexml_load_string($getXmlString);
echo 'xml: '.$orderLoaded;
```

This does not print anything because of the parser error...
Any clues?

Comment: on thing i forgot to say is that if i replace the double quotes for single quotes it works... im just curious why it doesn't with doubles (and what would be the easiestway to replace them?)

Comment: Those aren't double quotes, they are "smart quotes". Did you copy/paste the XML file from somewhere?

Comment: XDDDDDD I knew the answer was gonna reveal how stupid i am!!! you are right @Phylogenesis, that's the error :P

Answer (score 2):

It's because your XML is using smart quotes and not double qoutes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <products>
        <product title=”Rimmel Lasting Finish Lipstick 4g” price=”4.99”>
            <category>Lipstick</category>
        </product>
        <product title=”Sebamed Anti-Dandruff Shampoo 200ml” price=”4.99”>
            <category>Shampoo</category>
        </product>
    </products>
    <total>9.98</total>
</order>
```

Should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <products>
        <product title="Rimmel Lasting Finish Lipstick 4g" price="4.99">
            <category>Lipstick</category>
        </product>
        <product title="Sebamed Anti-Dandruff Shampoo 200ml" price="4.99">
            <category>Shampoo</category>
        </product>
    </products>
    <total>9.98</total>
</order>
```